# Limit :hover to the parent element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here come my example (found some pretty photos on the internet for you): http://jsfiddle.net/xGPys/ *(works on chrome only, if anyone finds why Firefox doesn't like it)*

So the part that causes me trouble is there:

```
.imagepreview:hover a {
    top: -61px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

What I want to achieve is: You should be able to pass you mouse on the whole column, and each image should open and close one after the other, right now, the opened photo covers the other ones, and so the `:hover` state is note removed from the `<td>`.

I could use a bit of Javascript but I'd prefer keeping it pure CSS.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) to `none`:

```css
.imagepreview a {
    /* ... other styles ... */
    pointer-events: none;
}
.imagepreview:hover a {
    top: -61px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xGPys/1/

---

**Warning:** `pointer-events` is *experimental*. Use at your own discretion.

Comment: Thanks dude, didn't knew you could use pointer-events for:hover, only used it for click events. It kills my link, but it works you'r awesome !